# Angular2 is there a way to set bootstrap col dynamically?

Tags: typescript, angular, ng-class

Is it possible to use an `If statement` to set the column width of the `div`? I have got different `div` elements like this:

```
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
            <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
                {{ p.selectorName }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1" *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
       <p class="text-center">If</p>
   </div>
```

How can I change the `col-xs-3` above to `col-xs-2` for example when `prototype?.valueType === 'Set'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ngClass`:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
    'col-xs-3': prototype?.valueType !== 'Set',
    'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}">
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 2):

I would leverage `NgClass` for this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set', 'col-xs-3': 'prototype?.valueType !== 'Set''}">
```